# Android O porting

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, porting, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to port android O to my device but encountering issue due to vendor partition not being created (which is mandatory for Android O), as a result the SELinux policy is not being fetched and boot process is being terminated. How can I create a vendor partition to flash the vendor image into.
my device runs on a Qualcomm msm8953 SOC.

below are the boot logs.

```
309800] nq-nci 5-0028: nqx_probe: probing nqxx failed, check hardware
[ 7.317273] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1196K
[ 7.321143] Freeing alternatives memory: 112K
[ 7.329257] init: init first stage started!
[ 7.332716] init: Using Android DT directory /proc/device-tree/firmware/android/
[ 7.724741] init: bool android::init::FirstStageMount::InitRequiredDevices(): partition(s) not found in /sys, waiting for their uevent(s): vendor
[ 8.878132] of_batterydata_get_best_profile: 2951034_foxda_ef501esp_3000mah_averaged_masterslave_jun6th2017 found
[ 8.894872] FG: fg_batt_profile_init: Battery SOC: 97, V: 4249242uV
[ 8.900528] of_batterydata_get_best_profile: 2951034_foxda_ef501esp_3000mah_averaged_masterslave_jun6th2017 found
[ 8.910371] SMBCHG: smbchg_config_chg_battery_type: Vfloat changed from 4400mV to 4350mV for battery-type 2951034_foxda_ef501esp_3000mah_averaged_masterslave_jun6th2017
[ 17.746065] init: Wait for partitions returned after 10009ms
[ 17.750729] init: bool android::init::FirstStageMount::InitRequiredDevices(): partition(s) not found after polling timeout: vendor
[ 17.768123] init: Failed to mount required partitions early ...
[ 17.773010] init: panic: rebooting to bootloader
[ 17.777611] init: Reboot start, reason: reboot, rebootTarget: bootloader
[ 17.784364] init: android::WriteStringToFile open failed: No such file or directory
[ 17.791947] init: Shutdown timeout: 0 ms
[ 17.795852] init: property_set("persist.vendor.crash.detect", "false") failed: __system_property_add failed
[ 17.805838] init: waitid failed: No child processes
[ 17.810437] init: vold not running, skipping vold shutdown
[ 17.916293] init: powerctl_shutdown_time_ms:138:0
[ 17.919991] init: Reboot ending, jumping to kernel
[ 17.924752] msm_thermal:msm_thermal_update_freq Freq mitigation task is not initialized
[ 17.978348] mdss_fb_release_all: try to close unopened fb 1! from pid:1 name:init
[ 17.984816] mdss_fb_release_all: try to close unopened fb 0! from pid:1 name:init
[ 17.993627] reboot: Restarting system with command 'bootloader'
[ 17.998538] Going down for restart now
[ 18.002831] qcom,qpnp-power-on qpnp-power-on-12: PMIC@SID2: configuring PON for reset
```

Comment: What device are you working on?

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering this myself and I believe it has to do with a mix of incomplete defconfig and dm-verity in the SoC's dts.  Unless you have worked it out by now.

In particular to incomplete defconfig, I had to add options like `CONFIG_PINCTRL_MSM8937=y` as my android device is technically a 8937.  Also, in `arch/arm/boot/dts/qcom/msm8937.dtsi` I needed to pull the `verify` flag from `fsmgr_flags`.

I now have other issues, but I am getting closer to booting.